# InterBase ToGo trial license does not work

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, interbase

(Interbase ToGo is an embedded version of the InterBase sql database.)

I am doing a simple evaluation of InterBase ToGo by accessing it from a Windows 7 app. However, when I run my application I get a popup saying "product INTERBASE is not licenced.". Dismissing the popup terminates my application.

I have carefully examined the files being opened using Sysinternal's Process Monitor tool, and as far as I can see the license files I got from Embarcadero (the company behind InterBase) are being read from the correct paths.

I also have over 80 days left of my 90-day trial license for IB ToGo, so that should not be a problem.

Has anyone gotten InterBase ToGo to work lately when using a trial license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works after all. The problem may likely have been that only one connection may be active at a time on an InterBase ToGo database. I may have had the database open in Rad Studio at the same time as I was trying to use it from a running application.

In this case I created a simple application with Rad Studio XE3. I used VCL and dbExpress for creating the application. The steps were:

1. Create database file with the **IBConnect** tool. This ensures texts are UTF-8 encoded (non-english texts). Make sure char/nchar columns have charset utf8 for good measure.
2. Create project in XE3
3. Add `TSQLConnection` and `TSQLDataSet` components to VCL form. Setup references amongst them.
4. Ensure "server charset" is utf8 on the connection.
5. Add a `TStringGrid` to the form
6. Create a livebinding from the Grid to to the Data Set.
7. Add an SQL statement to the Data Set, e.g. `select * from customers`
8. Ensure DataSet's `Open()` function is called.

The grid should now be filled with (example) data!